# JScrollbar doesnt activate when text goes over the width of the window

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextpane

here is my problem: I have a JTextPane, which I added to a JScrollpane. Now, when I write to the StyledDocument of this JTextPane and a line is longer than the width of the JTextPane it displays the rest of the line in a new line, instead of activating the scrollbar so that I can simply scroll to the end of the line.

Here is an image of what I mean:

[image]

In this picture, all the text should just be in one line and the horizontal scrollbar at the bottom should therefore be active.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

---

Edit1:

Here is the code I have at the moment:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame
{
    private ArrayList<RssFeed> rssFeeds = new ArrayList<RssFeed>();

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextPane newsPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public MainFrame() {
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(450, 300));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        newsPane = new JTextPane();
        newsPane.setEditable(false);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.add(newsPane);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(newsPane);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        final StyledDocument doc = newsPane.getStyledDocument();

        JPanel updateButton = new JPanel();
        FlowLayout fl_updateButton = (FlowLayout) updateButton.getLayout();
        fl_updateButton.setAlignment(FlowLayout.RIGHT);
        contentPane.add(updateButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JButton addUrlButton = new JButton("URL hinzuf\u00FCgen...");
        addUrlButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(MainFrame.this, "Bitte eine neue URL eingeben:", "Adresse der URL");
                if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MainFrame.this, "Keine URL eingegeben.", "Fehler", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                } else if (!str.endsWith(".xml") && !str.endsWith(".rss")) {
                    System.out.println(str);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MainFrame.this, "Die URL muss mit .xml oder .rss enden.", "Fehler", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    try {
                        RssFeed feed = new RssFeed(str);
                        rssFeeds.add(feed);
                        insertStringToDoc(feed.toString() + "\n", doc, doc.getLength());
                    } catch (XMLStreamException e1) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MainFrame.this, "Fehler beim Parsen des Rss-Feeds.", "Fehler", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MainFrame.this, "Fehler beim Lesen der Daten aus der URL.", "Fehler", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    } catch (RssException e1) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MainFrame.this, e1.getMessage(), "Fehler", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
            }
    });

    updateButton.add(addUrlButton);

    JButton deactivateSchedulerButton = new JButton("Scheduler deaktivieren");
    updateButton.add(deactivateSchedulerButton);

    JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("Update");
    updateButton.add(btnNewButton_2);
}

private void insertStringToDoc(String str, StyledDocument doc, int offset) {
    //puts text into the given document...
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
scrollPane.setViewportView(textPane);
```

That's what you're looking for, if the scroll is vertical. The scrollbar is activated when you write beyond the border of the scrollpane. Here's an example:

```
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
 import javax.swing.JTextPane;

public class Example extends JFrame {
    public Example()    {
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();

        scrollPane.setViewportView(textPane);
        add(scrollPane);

        setTitle("Example");
        setSize(300, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Example();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, though why both the lines `scrollPane.add(textPane)` and `scrollPane.setViewportView(textPane)`. They both doing the same thingy, as far as I can see. REST of the example is GOOD :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I already have this in my code (see my edit in the question) and it still behaves like I described...

Comment: I have edited it again and now posted quite all of my frame code.

Comment: @brgr : Why you using `Layout Manager` and `setBounds` together?, use `Layout Manager` only, that will suffice. And what's with `ScrollBarPolicy` why you needed that thingy?

Comment: `ScrollBarPolicy` makes it so that I always see the scrollbars, even if I can't scroll at the moment. `setBounds` sets the initial bounds of the window.

Comment: @brgr Works fine when I try to insert text to the newsPane. Maybe you are inserting text to the styled document, which does not have the viewportview set to it?

Comment: The problem is with space characters. It works as intended without them, but if you put space characters in the text, the text will make a new line there.

Comment: @brgr How about if you increase the width of the JFrame to accomodate the entire line? Programs arounds the problem and might look better

Comment: @brgr You can avoid the problem by not using a JTextPane. Use a normal panel instead and add the text as a label.

Comment: @danihodovic How do you add a viewport to a styled document?